# Why I do not get my latest code change from the Forked repository?

Tags: git, github

I have two branches in Git repository.

1. Master
2. Dev

I forked from Dev branch and did some changes and commited. My commits are need to be merged with **Dev** branch)

My local working files has some issues So, I deleted the project and again did

```
git clone  https://github.com/vijayaratha/portal.git
```

But im getting older code which is in the `Dev` branch why?

```
#git remote -v

origin  https://github.com/vijayaratha/portal.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/vijayaratha/portal.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/zz/portal.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/zz/portal.git (push)
```

When I check online, in my forked repository/dev branch I see the code changes. But Im not getting those, when I do git clone. Why?

My output for `git branch -av`

```
git branch -av
* master                5daacec Comment test code
  remotes/origin/HEAD   -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/dev    1811a3b Alarm acknowledge fix
  remotes/origin/master 5daacec Comment test code
```

If you see //  remotes/origin/dev // shows my last comment fro a fix

Comment: Did you `git push` your `dev` branch prior to deleting your local repository? If not, your changes are lost.

Comment: @Derek yes I did. And when I check online, in my forked repository/dev branch I see the code changes. But Im not getting those, when I do git clone. WHy?

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see you have two remotes. By your description seem to me that you are fetching the changes from one remote that does not have the changes that you pushed. Try to do `git fetch REMOTE` for each remote that you have, and then check out each Dev remote branch and see which one have the changes.

Comment: I did git fetch https://github.com/vijayaratha/portal.git  and getting //From https://github.com/vijayaratha/portal
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD//

Comment: I have pushed to my forked repository, but it is not merged with the original Dev branch.(Waiting for approval). I want to get my latest code from the forked repository, since it has my latest code changes

Comment: I would need a little more context here to help you ;) From what you said I can't figure out what is your forked repo or the original repo. I would say that you can clone your forked repo and then add manually the original repo as a remote. After that, you can go and do a fetch from the original and bum! be able to do the merges that you want. You can do the opposite too, clone from the original, adds the forked as remote and fetch from it. I would like to see after those operations the output of `git branch -av`. I hope this help ;)

Comment: I forked from Dev branch(named as Dev because development has to be in that branch) Here is the output //git branch -av
* master                5daacec Comment test code
  remotes/origin/HEAD   -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/dev    1811a3b Alarm acknowledge fix
  remotes/origin/master 5daacec Comment test code //

Comment: If you see // remotes/origin/dev // shows my last comment fro a fix I put the ouput clearly in my question

Comment: You go it then! Or I'm missing something? Just do a checkout of the branch that has your last commit and works from there. If you want to rebase that branch with the "father" repo, just add it as remote and fetch from it.

Comment: Yes..Im confused. Can you point me the URLs i need to clone? Im currently cloning from, https://github.com/vijayaratha/portal.git . Where master and dev have same URLs.

Comment: Yes, master and dev will have the same URL because URLs are per repo, not per branches. I highly recommend you take a look some basic GitHub workflow doc like [this post](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/01/27/using-fork-branch-git-workflow/), I'm not giving on you, is just that they will explain the basic concepts better than me in comments, and that is definitely what you need.